# error en Action Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Me sale:

> error undefined method `&' for "application":String

Estoy intentando hacer este método

```
def registro
    _layout 'application'
    @usuario = Usuarios.new
  end
end
```

es un formularios para registro de usuarios

gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Veo un par de errores, primero que el comando es `layout` y no `_layout`, lo segundo es que o debes usarlos fuera del contexto de la acción:

```
layout 'application'

def registro
  @usuario = Usuarios.new
end
```

o como parámetro de un render:

```
def registro
  @usuario = Usuarios.new
  render layout: 'application'
end
```

por último, el layout de `application` es el que viene por defecto, así que no es necesario que llames a layout.
Más información en la [documentación de rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: Lo pude resolver, muchas gracias, sabes integrar la API de Google Calendar a Rails tal vez? :)

Comment: @CamiloAndresQuiroga si te sirvió mi respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Si en realidad resolviste de otra forma, agrega tu respuesta por si a futuro alguien tiene tu mismo problema. Tus dudas con la API de Google Calendar lo puedes plantear como una nueva pregunta, para que así más gente pueda ayudarte. Todo esto es parte de la dinámica que hace funcionar al sitio. Saludos